# HTML Table do not add row until all present text box are filled and select is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below of my code clone's a new row with blank text box and drop down if the text box is keyup  and drop down is selected i have a problem is say i have four rows created by entering the values and drop down selected and when i recharge the value of first rows text box by making it empty a new row is created below perhaps there was already a blank row :

What i need is on text box keyup or drop down status changes that should check if a new row with blank text box is present at last row then it should not create a row until expect last row text box is empty and select is not selected.

[DEMO js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/99pvwypp/7/)

CSS:

```
.hide {
    display: none;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="results"></div>

<input id="buttonclck" type="button" class="hide" value="button"/>
```

JS:

```
$('#results').append('<table width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" id="productanddates" class="border"> <tr><td> <input type="text" name="to1" id="to1" value="" /> </td> <td> <select class="dd" name="Phonenumberdd1" id="Phonenumberdd1"> <option value="test">test </option><option value="test2">test 2</option></select></td> <td>   <input type="text" name="renewal_by1" id="renewal_by1" />  </td>   <td> <input type="text" name="Renivaul_to1" id="Renivaul_to1" value="" /> </td></TR></TABLE>'
);

    $('#results').on('focus', ':input', function() {
        $(this).closest('tr').filter(function() { 
            return !$(this).data('saved'); 
        })
        .find(':input').each(function() {
            $(this).data('value', this.value);
            $(this).closest('tr').data('saved', true);
        });
    })
    .on('input change', ':input', function() {
        $(this).data('filled', this.value != $(this).data('value'))
        var tr  = $(this).closest('tr');
            all = tr.find(':input'),
            fld = all.filter(function() {
                return $(this).data('filled');
            });
        if( all.length == fld.length ) {
            if( !tr.data('done') ) {
                $('#buttonclck')[0].click();
                tr.data('done', true);
            }
        } else {
            if( tr.data('done') ) {

                tr.data('done', false);
            }
        }
    });

    $('#buttonclck').on('click', function () {
        var lastRow = $('#productanddates').closest('#productanddates').find("tr:last-child");

        var cloned = lastRow.clone();
        cloned.find('input, select').each(function () {
            var id = $(this).attr('id');

            var regIdMatch = /^(.+)(\d+)$/;
            var aIdParts = id.match(regIdMatch);
            var newId = aIdParts[1] + (parseInt(aIdParts[2], 10) + 1);

            $(this).attr('id', newId);
            $(this).attr('name', newId);
        });

        cloned.find("input[type='text']").val('');
        cloned.insertAfter(lastRow);
    });
```

Comment: Have you tried to implement the feature on your own? What's the problem? Do you have any trouble detecting inputs being filled, or...?

Comment: @FelisCatus the problem is a new row is created at the bottom on change of drop down or text box data is refilled or re selected i need a row to be crated only if the last row of text box or dropdown changes  if still not understud can you join me hear http://jsfiddle.net/99pvwypp/11/#&togetherjs=ICJ17R7yMt

Comment: I observe that the select is not treated as "filled" even if it has a default value in the beginning. Changing its value, however, sets the "filled" flag. Is this the problem?

Comment: nop the problem was if u have understood on every row there are text box and drop down on text box fill and the drop down change a new row is cloned same say i have created 4 rows by filling then according to code there should be a empty text box and default selected drop down on 5th row ::hear is the problem on edit or recharge of text box of first row a new 6th row is created which should not as the row was edited

Comment: if u don't mind can you join me in the filled i can explain over there http://jsfiddle.net/99pvwypp/11/#&togetherjs=ICJ17R7yMt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the working fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/99pvwypp/16/.

```
 var isClone = false;
 lastRowInputs.each(function() {
     if($(this).val().length) {
       isClone = true;
     }
 });
 if(!isClone)
    return false;
```

Just added a condition check for previously filled rows.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the following lines starting from L25 works for me:

```
    else {
        if( tr.data('done') ) {

            tr.data('done', false);
        }
    }
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/99pvwypp/12/

Once a row is done, you don't have to worry about it any more. Otherwise that row can be used to trigger `$('#buttonclck')[0].click();` more than one time, which gives you an extra new row. If you need the `done` flag for other purposes such as form validation, you can add a new flag named `filledOnce` to prevent duplicates.

For the `select`s, one solution would be treat them as filled initially.

```
.on('input change', ':input', function() {
    $('#results select').data('filled', true); // Added
    // .... rest of this function unchanged
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/99pvwypp/17/

Another would be requiring the user to manually click on the `select`. I don't think this is very user-friendly, but...

```
.on('input change click', ':input', function() { // Added click here
    $(this).data('filled', this.tagName === 'SELECT' || this.value != $(this).data('value')). // Modified for SELECT
    // Unchanged
});
```

Comment: Thanks was expecting the same a small problem is on drop down change row is created can that should be applicable same as textboxs

Comment: am not sure u understand my problem what i expect if u don't mind and if i can have some of your time i request you to join me in fiddle i can explain you live http://jsfiddle.net/99pvwypp/15/#&togetherjs=ICJ17R7yMt